# Spring - Integration test of MultipartFileUpload with container and custom validator

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

### The problem

I'm trying to write an integration test with the goal of verifying a file upload.

The normal file upload works as intended (the file is uploaded when fulfilling the requirements), but the test does not execute and throws an error.

```
Invalid target for Validator [my.package.here.validators.FileContainerValidator#0 bean]: my.package.here.models.FileContainer@7661b5a
```

As an extra information, I'm looking for an *annotation-based* solution

---

### Current code base

Thymeleaf file upload form:

```
        <form method="POST" action="#" th:action="@{/upload}" th:object="${fileContainer}"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" th:field="*{file}" id="file"/>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <label for="destination">Destination:</label>
            <input type="text" value="/tmp" id="destination" th:field="*{destination}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload"/>
       </form>
```

FileUploadController:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private final FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    FileContainerValidator fileContainerValidator;

    @Autowired
    public void setDefaultFileContainerValidator(FileContainerValidator validator) {
        this.fileContainerValidator = validator;
    }

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController(FileStorageService FileStorageService) {
        this.fileStorageService = FileStorageService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/upload")
    public String showTestFileUploadForm(@ModelAttribute Mapping mapping, FileContainer fileContainer, Model model) {
        String path = "ERROR";
        try {
            path = new ClassPathResource("data.csv").getFile().getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        model.addAttribute("shortenedFile", new TableConstructor(path, mapping.getContentDelimiter()));
        return "upload";
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@Valid FileContainer fileContainer, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for (ObjectError e : result.getAllErrors())
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.toString());
            //TODO: Error msg
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fetching file");
            fileStorageService.store(fileContainer);
            //TODO: SUCCESS
        }
        return "redirect:/upload";
    }

    @InitBinder("fileContainer")
    protected void initBinderFileContainer(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(fileContainerValidator);
    }
}
```

FileContainer class:

```
public class FileContainer implements Serializable {
    private MultipartFile file;
    private String destination;

    public FileContainer(MultipartFile file, String destination) {
        Assert.notNull(file, "The file must not be null or empty!");
    }

    //Unused but needed for string
    public FileContainer() {
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }


    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        Assert.notNull(file, "The file must not be null or empty!");
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

And last but not least, the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(FileUploadController.class)
public class FileUploadIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @MockBean
    private FileContainerValidator fileContainerValidator;

    private MockMultipartFile correctFile =
            new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.xml", "text/plain", "some xml".getBytes());

    private MockMultipartFile fileWithWrongExtension =
            new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "this is a wrong file!".getBytes());

    private String testDestination = "/tmp";

    @Test
    public void uploadMultipartTestFile() throws Exception {
       mockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/upload")
                .file(correctFile)
                .param("destination", testDestination))
                .andExpect(
                        model().attributeExists("fileContainer")
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Controller InitBinders's `binder.setValidator` method is invoked by test runner it throws "Invalid target for Validator" error. You can return "true" by stubbing `supports` method of Validator class. One more thing, your FileContainer class has property "file" while in your MockMultipartFile you are using "data". This will cause null file to be uploaded by test.

```
    @Autowired 
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void uploadMultipartTestFile() throws Exception {
     MockMultipartFile correctFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "C:\\temp\\test.txt".getBytes());        
     MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
     when(fileContainerValidator.supports(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(true);
     mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/upload")
                .file(correctFile)
                .param("destination", "/tmp"))
                .andExpect(content().string("redirect:/upload")
                 );
    }
```

Comment: You should explain what problem you identified and how your code solves that problem. Just posting a piece of code is not a very high quality answer

Comment: @raniz Edited the answer and added details.

Comment: Thanks to you for the great explaination and the code!